# Add portion of filepath as a prefix to a filename for all files in a folder

Tags: bash

I'm trying to rename files based on the upstream directory name but I don't have any bash script experience.

Let's say I have a directory that contains thousands of directories named "k99_xxx_properties", and in each k99 directory there is an Alignments directory, and in the Alignments directory there are files named sample1, sample2, sample3 in and so on. What I want to do is rename the sample files by adding the "k99_xxx" portion of the upstream directory as a prefix ("k99_xxx_sample1").

I know all I need to do is loop through all k99_xxx_properties directories, save the k99_xxx portion of the directory name as a variable, and navigate into each k99_xxx, cd into Alignments, and loop through every file in Alignments to add k99_xxx as a prefix for the sample filenames.

How would I go about that in a bash script?

Answer (score 0):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code is a straightforward translation of the description in the question into Bash:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing

# Loop through all k99_xxx_properties directories
for k99dir in k99_*_properties/ ; do
    # Save the k99_xxx portion of the directory name as a variable
    k999_xxx=${k99dir%_properties/}

    # (Skip the directory if it doesn't have an 'Alignments' subdirectory)
    [[ -d ${k99dir}Alignments ]] || continue

    # navigate into each k99_xxx, cd into Alignments
    (
        cd -- "${k99dir}Alignments" || exit

        # loop through every file in Alignments to add k99_xxx
        # as a prefix for the sample filenames.
        for sf in sample* ; do
            echo mv -- "$sf" "${k999_xxx}_${sf}"
            mv -- "$sf" "${k999_xxx}_${sf}"
        done
    )
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` is to prevent the code trying to process spurious 'k99_*_properties' directories or 'sample*' files if it is run where they do not exist.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${k99dir%_properties/}`.
- The parentheses around the statements starting at `cd ...` cause them to be run in a subshell.  This means that the `cd` (and the possible `exit`) doesn't affect the current shell.  The advantage is that there is no need to `cd` back to the starting directory for the next iteration of the outer loop.  It is not always possible to `cd` back to a directory after using `cd` to leave it.
- The conditional `exit` after `cd` (which only exits the surrounding (subshell-creating) parentheses) is to prevent trying to do file moves in the wrong directory if `cd` fails.  [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) complains if the `exit` is not present (which is one of the reasons why it's a good idea to always use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on shell code).
- Since it is executed in a directory different from the current one, the output of `echo mv ...` may be confusing.  (This is one of the reasons why it's best to avoid using `cd` in programs.  It's generally best to do operations from the current directory.)